# Using PMD default rules with properties

Tags: java, rules, pmd

How to use the dafault rules with properties in PMD.

Now I'm using the default rules as

```
<rule ref="rulesets/basic.xml/UselessOperationOnImmutable"/>
```

this works fine but the rules like "NPathComplexity" in Codesize use properties so that we can configure the default rules too . how to configure this . someone please help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml/CyclomaticComplexity">
  <properties>
     <property name="reportLevel" value="5"/>
  </properties>
</rule>
```

is working fine.